# Sorting Algorithms & Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

Which is the Fastest Sorting Algorithm in terms of Time Complexity considerations?

Among the commonly used sorting algorithms like
Bubble sort, Insertion sort, Merge Sort, Heap Sort etc which is the fastest?

Comment: Look for `TimSort` and `SmoothSort`. Those are uncommon but fast options.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
I was asking myself this question a while ago, and I decided to go ahead and write some code to figure that out. The chart is displaying number of inputs on the `x` axis and time on the `y` axis.

As you can see from the image, RadixSort is generally the fastest, followed by QuickSort. Their **time complexities** are:

- **RadixSort**: O(N*W), where N is the number of elements to sort and W is the number of bits required to store each key.
- **QuickSort**: O(N*logN), where N is the number of elements to sort.

Anyway, RadixSort speed comes at a cost. In fact, the **space complexities** of the two algorithms are the following:

- **RadixSort**: O(N+W), where N is the number of elements to sort and W is the number of bits required to store each key.
- **QuickSort**: O(logN), or O(N) depending on how the pivots are chosen: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138335/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-quicksort.

Comment: QuickSort can't really be done in O(1) space. On average, it requires O(log n) space for the recursion stack frames. A poorly-written QuickSort could end up requiring O(n) stack space and take O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**                             **Time Complexities**
                   Best                 Average                        Worst

```
Selection Sort    Ω(n^2)                 θ(n^2)                      O(n^2)
Bubble Sort       Ω(n)                   θ(n^2)                      O(n^2)
Insertion Sort    Ω(n)                   θ(n^2)                      O(n^2)
Heap Sort         Ω(n log(n))            θ(n log(n))                 O(n log(n))
Quick Sort        Ω(n log(n))            θ(n log(n))                 O(n^2)
Merge Sort        Ω(n log(n))            θ(n log(n))                 O(n log(n))
Bucket Sort       Ω(n+k)                 θ(n+k)                      O(n^2) 
Radix Sort        Ω(nk)                  θ(nk)                       O(nk)
```

The time complexity of Quicksort is O(n log n) in the best case, O(n log n) in the average case, and O(n^2) in the worst case. But because it has the best performance in the average case for most inputs, Quicksort is generally considered the “fastest” sorting algorithm.